Is this description of The End of Eternity correct in any translation
In this wikipedia article, the plot section describes the advertisement that provides the vital clue in this way:

Harlan finds that a magazine from 1932 has changed and now shows an
advertisement in the form of a mushroom cloud, which no human could
have known of in 1932. The first letters in the ad's four words, A
Tomic Energy Makes, ATEM, sound like ATOM.

In English copies of the book the ad reads:
All the
Talk
Of the
Market,
spelling out ATOM.
Is the wiki page just wrong in a bizarre way, or has someone who read the book in some other language described how the clue was translated to fit that language?

Not sure why this was changed in the article.  "All the Talk Of the Market" was part of the plot synopsis until the edit on 18:12, 7 July 2017‎‎, at which point it was removed.  The incorrect version now placed back on the page was added in the edit on 18:46, 21 August 2024.  Could very well be from a translated edition.  Since it's a wiki I'll just put it back. :)

Thsnk you. My ip is blocked for some reason, or I would have done it

@Qev You might want to make an answer out of our comment for Andrew to accept.

Not sure why this was changed in the article. "All the Talk Of the Market" was part of the plot synopsis until the edit on 18:12, 7 July 2017‎‎, at which point it was removed. The incorrect version now placed back on the page was added in the edit on 18:46, 21 August 2024. Could very well be from a translated edition. Since it's a wiki I'll just put it back. :)
